# Alternative of SonarQube for React Native?

Tags: react-native, sonarqube

I hope you all are doing amazing!

I have been using sonarqube for react native but it seems like for react native sonarqube is not compatible so could you please suggest an alternative of sonarqube for React Native.

I look forward to hearing from you guys!

Thank You,
Hardik

Comment: Could you find a good alternative?